# How can I align a horizontal scroll bar's position to the right of a resizing window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When resizing a page, the default behavior is that the size of the scroll bar shrinks towards the left or upper end of the scroll bar, keeping that portion fixed on the screen. However, I want to reverse this by aligning it to the right. 
I'm implementing a fixed-sized graph timeline inside a div that's responsive w.r.t. the browser window and I'd like to keep the right part of the graph in view as I resize the window (as opposed to the left) since the right edge of the chart contains the most recent data.

Comment: Are you using the native, user-agent, scroll bar or a custom widget?

Comment: The native one generated by the browser when you set overflow-x/y: scroll;